# Linker Error C++ Source file not compiling

Tags: c++, visual-studio-code

I am currently a beginner to learning C++ and I am just unable to solve this error or find an answer online. Also I am a beginner so sorry if anything here seems dumb.

I am trying to link a header file named Account.h to my main.cpp file. However, I keep getting the following error:

```
"Account::set_balance(double)", referenced from:
      _main in main-369b54.o
  "Account::deposit(double)", referenced from:
      _main in main-369b54.o
  "Account::set_name(std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> >)", referenced from:
      _main in main-369b54.o
  "Account::withdraw(double)", referenced from:
      _main in main-369b54.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

I have a header file called Account.h, a source file called Account.cpp, and a main file called main.cpp. All my files are in a single folder. How do solve this linker error? I am using VSCode on MacOS.

I have #include a header file(Account.h) into the source file(Account.cpp). I can post my code below:

main.cpp: (Account.h is in #include in my file)

```
int main(){
    Account frank_account;
    frank_account.set_name("Frank");
    frank_account.set_balance(1000.0);

    if(frank_account.deposit(200.0))
        cout << "Deposit OK" << endl;
    else cout << "Deposit not allowed" << endl;
    
    if(frank_account.withdraw(500.0))
        cout << "Withdraw OK" << endl;
    else cout << "Not sufficient funds" << endl;

    if(frank_account.withdraw(1500.0))
        cout << "Withdraw OK" << endl;
    else cout << "Not sufficient funds" << endl;

}
```

Account.cpp

```
#include "Account.h"

void Account::set_balance(double bal){
    balance = bal;
}
double Account::get_balance(){
    return balance;
}

void Account::set_name(std::string n){
    name = n;
}

std::string Account::get_name(){
    return name;
}

bool Account::deposit(double amount){
    //if verify amount
    balance += amount;
    return true;
}

bool Account::withdraw(double amount){
    if(balance - amount >= 0){
        balance -= amount;
        return true;
    } else 
        return false;

}
```

How can I make sure that when I run the main file. the source file also compiles and I don't get the linker error? I tried the following command:

```
g++ -o main.cpp Account.cpp
```

and as well as

```
g++ -Wall -std=c++17 main.cpp Account.cpp
```

but I keep getting the linker error. How do I resolve this problem?

Thanks!

Comment: `linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)`

Comment: Please provide a [mre] including the exact compile commands, I doubt `g++ -o main.cpp Account.cpp` is the command you are using as it would compile account.cpp into an object file called main.cpp. have you saved all your files before compiling?

Comment: VS Code does not automatically save - you need to save all before building.  Also your errors do not match up with your source code.

Comment: Edit your question and provide `Account.h` to enable those here to re-create your issue and enlist the aid of the compiler and linker in solving your problem. Without seeing `Account.h` you are asking everyone here to guess.